# What is the best place for uploading files when spilt frontend and backend?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, frontend, backend, nuxt.js

hi i working to spilt backend (laravel) and frontend(nuxt.js)
and i want to know best place to upload dynamic images or files on the.

- backend (laravel): public folder.

or

- frontend (nuxtjs): asstes/images folder.

and i want when i finished my project upload it on same server with different port.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are static files used in the frontend, then in the assets/images from nuxtjs. 
If those are files uploaded to the server, then in the laravel backend.

Comment: in that case in the server side.

Comment: @iFahdDev If your question is answered you can mark as solved